# model.save_weights and model.load_weights not working as expected

Tags: python, serialization, neural-network, theano, keras

I'm new to machine learning and am going through the courses on [fast.ai](http://course.fast.ai/index.html). We're learning about vgg16, and I'm having trouble saving my model. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. When I start my model from scratch, training to learn the difference between cats and dogs, I get:

```
from __future__ import division,print_function
from vgg16 import Vgg16
import os, json
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import utils; reload(utils)
from utils import plots


np.set_printoptions(precision=4, linewidth=100)
batch_size=64

path = "dogscats/sample"
vgg = Vgg16()
# Grab a few images at a time for training and validation.
# NB: They must be in subdirectories named based on their category
batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'/train', batch_size=batch_size)
val_batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'/valid', batch_size=batch_size*2)
vgg.finetune(batches)
no_of_epochs = 4
latest_weights_filename = None
for epoch in range(no_of_epochs):
    print ("Running epoch: %d" % epoch)
    vgg.fit(batches, val_batches, nb_epoch=1)
    latest_weights_filename = ('ft%d.h5' % epoch)
    vgg.model.save_weights(path+latest_weights_filename)
print ("Completed %s fit operations" % no_of_epochs)

Found 160 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 40 images belonging to 2 classes.
Running epoch: 0
Epoch 1/1
160/160 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 1.8980 - acc: 0.6125 - val_loss: 0.5442 - val_acc: 0.8500
Running epoch: 1
Epoch 1/1
160/160 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.7194 - acc: 0.8563 - val_loss: 0.2167 - val_acc: 0.9500
Running epoch: 2
Epoch 1/1
160/160 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.1809 - acc: 0.9313 - val_loss: 0.1604 - val_acc: 0.9750
Running epoch: 3
Epoch 1/1
160/160 [==============================] - 4s - loss: 0.2733 - acc: 0.9375 - val_loss: 0.1684 - val_acc: 0.9750
Completed 4 fit operations
```

But now when I go to load one of the weight files, the model starts from scratch! For example, I would have expected the model below to have a val_acc of 0.9750! Am I misunderstanding something or doing something wrong? Why is the val_acc so low with this loaded model?

```
vgg = Vgg16()
vgg.model.load_weights(path+'ft3.h5')
batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'/train', batch_size=batch_size)
val_batches = vgg.get_batches(path+'/valid', batch_size=batch_size*2)
vgg.finetune(batches)
vgg.fit(batches, val_batches, nb_epoch=1)

Found 160 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 40 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/1
160/160 [==============================] - 6s - loss: 1.3110 - acc: 0.6562 - val_loss: 0.5961 - val_acc: 0.8250
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in a `finetune` function. When you get deeper into its definition:

```
def finetune(self, batches):
    model = self.model
    model.pop()
    for layer in model.layers: layer.trainable=False
    model.add(Dense(batches.nb_class, activation='softmax'))
    self.compile()
```

... one can see that by calling `pop` function - the last layer of your model is deleted. By doing this you are losing information from a trained model. The last layer is added again with random weights and then training starts again. This is the reason behind the accuracy drop.

Comment: Thanks! I moved my `load_weights` to below my `vgg.finetun(batches)` and everything worked as expected! :)